# Hexagonal image in object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have used a `scrollView` in my page in order to display maximum 10 Images. Images are displayed in a **hexagonal** shape but not in the shape i want. Now it looks like [current hex shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPlo2.png)
but i need to show like this- [hex shape i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr7Ek.png)
I am posting my code below. Please anyone can guide me.

```
-(CAShapeLayer*)ChangeShape:(UIView*)view
{

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
maskLayer.frame = view.bounds;

CGFloat width = view.frame.size.width;
CGFloat height = view.frame.size.height;
CGFloat hPadding = width * 1 / 8 / 2;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(width/2, 0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width - hPadding, height / 4)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width - hPadding, height * 3 / 4)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width / 2, height)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(hPadding, height * 3 / 4)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(hPadding, height / 4)];
[path closePath];
[path closePath];
[path fill];
[path stroke];

maskLayer.path = path.CGPath;

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return maskLayer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `ChangeShape` function like this

```
-(CAShapeLayer*)ChangeShape:(UIView*)view{
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
    maskLayer.frame = view.bounds;

    CGFloat width = view.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat height = view.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat hPadding = width * 1 / 8 / 2;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, height / 2)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width / 4 , hPadding)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width * 3 / 4, hPadding)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width, height / 2)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width * 3 / 4, height - hPadding)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width / 4, height - hPadding)];
    [path closePath];
    [path fill];
    [path stroke];

    maskLayer.path = path.CGPath;

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return maskLayer;
}
```